# React Spectrum component TagGroup remove icon only for necessary items

Tags: reactjs, adobe

When we use component TagGroup we can set up remove icon for all items in list but I need some items without it. Does anyone have any ideas how to implement this?

I see that in the old versions of the library there was such an opportunity, but for some reason they removed it in the new one.
Current library version 3.29.0.